# method throws NumberFormatException where it shouldnt, worked normally so far

Tags: java, numberformatexception

I cant seem to figure out why it thows NFE when the string i am converting is an int

[code]

```
 public void setCurrentTransferRate(){
    try{
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();  
        String[] command = {"/bin/sh", "-c", "ifconfig " + interface_name + " | grep -oP     'RX bytes:[0-9]{1,11}'"};
        String[] command1 = {"/bin/sh", "-c", "ifconfig " + interface_name + " | grep -oP 'TX bytes:[0-9]{1,11}'"};
        Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        Process child1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command1);
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(child.getInputStream()));       //i prwti metrisi twn RX kai TX bytes
        BufferedReader r1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(child1.getInputStream()));
        String temp = r.readLine();
        temp = temp.replace("RX bytes:","");   
        String temp1 = r1.readLine();
        temp1 = temp1.replace("TX bytes:","");  
        r.close();              
        r1.close();
        int x = Integer.parseInt(temp);         
        int y = Integer.parseInt(temp1); 
    }catch(IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}        
    catch(InterruptedException e){e.printStackTrace();}
   }[/code]
```

the string that is producing the error is temp

and i get the error

[code]

```
 Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:  "3262469144"
  at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:495)
  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
  at askisi1.General.setCurrentTransferRate(General.java:187)
  at askisi1.General.<init>(General.java:27) 
  at askisi1.mainThread.run(mainThread.java:17)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)[/code]
```

I could really use a fresh pair of eyes on this

Comment: jesus that was easy...i feel stupid for not noticing it but i guess coding for hours on end really has its toll..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The maximum positive value for an integer is [`Integer.MAX_VALUE` which is `2,147,483,647`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE). You could use a long instead:

```
long x = Long.parseLong(temp);
```

and it should solve your problem (if all your numbers are less than [`Long.MAX_VALUE` or `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#MAX_VALUE)).

Answer (score 4):

3262469144 is too big for an int!